# get videos from android gallery to android app activity screen

Tags: android

I am designing a small application for android. I have videos saved in my gallery. I want to retrieve and show a list/thumbnail of all videos saved in my gallery which on click start playing in the video player.
I have no idea how to do it since i am new to android. Kindly explain your answer briefly.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get [list of videos](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#managedQuery%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) from Gallery and show them in a [ListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). You can have a `ImageView` for the video thumbnail and `TextView` for description or time etc.

You can create the Thumbnails as below in the `GetView` method.

```
ImageView imageThumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Thumbnail);
Bitmap bmThumbnail;
bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(PATH_TO_VIDEO_IN_STRING, Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
imageThumbnail.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

People here will expect you to do some coding before asking the question. I hope you can start up with this.